# Delete Outlook Items by Subject line and Sender Email address

Tags: vba, outlook

Below is the macro to delete outlook emails however the code is giving error **`"Type Mismatch"`** at the very last line **`"Next Mails_itm"`**.

```
Dim Out_App As Outlook.Application
Dim Folders As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Mails_itm As MailItem

Set start_fm = Range("a1")
Set Out_App = New Outlook.Application
Set Folders = Out_App.GetNamespace("mapi")
Set MyFolder = Folders.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each Mails_itm In MyFolder.Items
    If Mails_itm.Subject = "my_very_specific_subject_line" Then
        Mails_itm.Delete
    End If
Next Mails_itm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs due to missing item objects which were put into loop collection at the beginning, and have been deleted within loop. Try to use a loop with `Step -1` so that you start deleting from the last item:

```
Set myitems = myfolder.Items
For i = myitems.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set mails_itm = myitems(i)
    If mails_itm.Subject = "my_very_specific_subject_line" And _
    mails_itm.Sender = "my_very_specific_from_line" Then
        mails_itm.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Need to add condition to check From field as well.

Comment: @RajatSharma check the answer, I added sender check as requested.

Comment: The code that I mentioned it was working fine but now its not. I have not changed anything. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @RajatSharma please edit your question. Add the modified code you ran. Show the error line and description.

Comment: @omegastripes : Looping through all items in a folder is as bad as it gets - never do that. Use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.

Answer (score 4):

*You may wanna use [Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which will Apply a filter to the Items collection and returning a new collection containing all of the items from the match filter.*

*Example*

*Set your Filter by 
`"[Subject] = 'Subject_line' And [SenderEmailAddress] = 'Sender@Email.com'"`*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Delete_Emails()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Filter = "[Subject] = 'Subject_line' And [SenderEmailAddress] = 'from_email'"
    
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
    Msg = Items.Count & " items in " & Inbox.Name & ". Delete?"
    
    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print Items(i) 'Immediate Window
            Items.remove i
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> *<sub>This method is an alternative to using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx) method or [FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482.aspx) method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The Find or FindNext methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.</sub>*

[*Item.Remove method (Outlook) MSDN*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.itemproperties.remove) *Removes an object from the collection.*

Comment: Since you suggest `.Remove` method instead of OP's `.Delete` it would be a good thing to describe the difference.

Comment: @0m3r thank you tremendously. Is there documentation of filtering for the current day?