# Deleting a single selected Outlook Message using Python & Selenium

Tags: python, outlook, selenium-chromedriver, win32com, office-automation

I have code that polls my outlook main inbox for a 2 factor authentication email, finds a string, and copies it to the web page and hits enter.

I would like to delete the email message after this.

I'm not sure where I've made the mistake in the code.

I didn't write the original python and intend to modify it to find the newest message and use that one instead of the len(messages)==1 criteria but I will still want to delete the message when I am done.

```
#Part 2: Retreive passcode from email for authentication
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
delay = 15 #seconds
waitloop = 1
passcodefound = 0
while passcodefound == 1:
    print ("Authentication email found.")
    break # it will break from the loop once the specific element will be present.
else:
    print("waiting for " + str(delay)+ " seconds.")
    time.sleep(delay)
    messages = inbox.Items
    messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
    messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = '  '")
    messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = ' '")
    print("filtered inbox, " + str(len(messages))+" found.")
    if len(messages) == 1:
        for message in messages:
            text=message.Body
            CodeRegexVariable=re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d)')
            code=CodeRegexVariable.search(str(text))
            answer=code.group()
            print(answer)
            print("2 Factor Authentication email found and processed.")
            passcodefound = 1
            passcode_field=driver.find_element(By.ID," ")
            passcode_field.clear()
            passcode_field.send_keys( )
            submit_button=driver.find_element(By.ID,"otpSubmitButton")
            submit_button.click()
            **message.Delete**
            break
    else:
        waitloop = waitloop+1
        total_wait_time = waitloop * delay
        print ("Authentication email not found. Wait time total = " + str(total_wait_time) + " seconds. Waiting for "+str(delay)+" seconds and trying again")
```

I moved the message.Delete line earlier to just after print("2 Factor Authentication email found and processed.") with the same result.

I unindented the message.Delete and break lines and i got an error for breaking outside of a loop
I unindented the message.Delete and commented out the break with no error, but the message isn't deleted.

Comment: see example on deleting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39634217/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot restrict by calling Restrict multiple times - call Restrict once and combine all 3 criteria by concatenating them with the `"AND"` operator:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "' AND " & _
                             "[SenderEmailAddress] = '  ' AND " & _
                             "[Subject] = ' '")
```

Secondly, if you still want to delete all messages even if more than one found, chnage the `if len(messages) == 1:` condition to `if len(messages) > 0:`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Neither combining the filters or the deleting.

Comment: Please be more specific: what does "didn't work" mean? What is your actual query? Are you getting a particular error? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

*Try working with [MailItem.Delete method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.delete)*

*Example delete selected item*

```
message.Delete()
```

---

```
import win32com.client    

def outlook_item(messages):
    if messages.Count > 0:
        print(messages.Count)
        for message in reversed(range(messages.Count, 0, -1)):
            print(message)
            message.Delete()
    else:
        print("Nothing selected.")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    olApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.Application")
    items = olApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection
    outlook_item(items)
```